# Flutter doesn't run application on an attached device in command prompt, while android studio is closed ( running only in android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, command-line, usb-debugging

I installed Flutter and everything required for that. Then because AVD runs really slow for debugging i used connected hardware device (Redmi 7) - within Android Studio app runs on connected device perfectly, but when I try to run it from command prompt it tells me that some download have failed:

C:\Users\vasil\first_app>flutter run

Downloading windows-x64/flutter-cpp-client-wrapper tools...

Download failed.

URL:
https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/flutter/0b330467da244c86637db5fdaa5ef5401e90beba/windows-x64/flutter-cpp-client-wrapper.zip

Error: 404 Not Found

Please help me, what can i do to improve this error and run my flutter app from cmd on connected device for debugging?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try running flutter doctor,
flutter clean ,
flutter upgrade,before doing anything else as this problem is rela

Answer (score 0):

It's a Known problem, as seen here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64041

Always add your flutter doctor for compiling problems.

The correction was made but is not available yet. I suggest you to downgrade you flutter version or to wait a little bit for the fix to be available.